# process vmstat log files using script/application

Tags: virtual-machine, solaris, sunos

I want to monitor the performance metrics of solaris 10 server like average memory and cpu usage. At the moment i have set up a script to run vmstat once every x seconds and log to a file.

```
 vmstat x >> perf.log  

  kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
  r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr f0 s0 s1 s2   in   sy   cs us sy id
  2 0 104 15060736 1126784 828 3735 43 51 55 0 3991 -0 18 -1 65 6707 24478 14096 14 12 74
  0 0 93 13532024 292920 28 309 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0 34 4366 4388 4019  4  4 92
  2 0 93 13534872 294296 1 12 0  0  0  0  0  0 19  0 50 2688 3834 3630  4  5 91
  0 0 93 13533704 293100 1 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20 2624 3437 3147  3  3 94
  0 0 93 13541768 296136 16 349 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  0 44 2746 2936 3932  6  7 88
  1 0 93 13535512 291116 1 4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 28 2637 3736 3317  4  2 93
  1 0 93 13516860 279432 45 361 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0 44 3526 7851 5398  7  4 89
  0 0 93 13531864 288964 15 61 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 32 2798 3944 3500  3  3 94
  1 0 93 13530516 287520 1 313 0 0  0  0  0  0 12  0 88 3527 7962 5280  7  5 88
```

Now I need to analyse this log file and compute the average memory and cpu usage. Is there any tool available for this, or even a better way to do this.

Edit: Found a tool https://github.com/jsargiot/vmstatly

Comment: for java you can use `visualVM` [Link](http://visualvm.java.net)

Comment: Thank you, I use jvisualVM, but it has the same problem. I want to find out the average CPU & memory usage, it doesn't show the average, it gives a nice graph but that's not what I want.

Comment: https://github.com/jsargiot/vmstatly does what i wanted.